# Apply formatting to all cells except first one in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I would like apply cell formatting to all cells except first one. I need this because first line contains description. How to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried to select the cells that you want to apply the format, and apply it to them? If that isn't what are you looking for describe what you are looking for.

Comment: I suppose I can't select all cells without pressing column label. But this will select all cells. But I need all_cells - first_one.

Comment: Check the Google Sheets keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Ctrl-A to select all cells, then Ctrl-click to de-select the one cell you don't want formatted. Does this not work for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the easiest way is to click the cell in second row, then scroll to the bottom of the sheet (using the scrollbar on the right) and Shift-click the cell in the last row.

To select all cells in the sheet, except for the first row, proceed similarly but clicking the row numbers instead: Click Row 2 -> Scroll to the bottom -> Shift-click last row.

Answer (score 2):

A2:{ColumnLetter}(omit row number)

This will select row A2 and everything underneath it until the specified column. To be more specific, this syntax can be used to create a box, where the top left corner is the first index, with a width that goes until the second index (the column letter w/o a number). This box will go all the way to the bottom of the sheet.

Ex:

- A2:E
- A2:Z
- A10:J
- K6:M